# 拡張機能で拡張機能内のjsonファイルを読み取りたい

Tags: javascript, json, chrome-extension

#### 全体のやりたいこと

webサイトで実装されている通知を拡張機能で検知し、ブロックリストに登録されているurlが遷移先urlになっている場合通知をブロックする
拡張機能で拡張機能内のjsonファイル（ブロックリスト）を読み込んでjsonファイル内に登録されているurlと取得してきた遷移先urlと比較したい。
方法はfetchでもxmlhttprequestでも構いません。

#### 今回やりたいこと

拡張機能内で拡張機能内のjsonファイルを読み取りたい
`content.js`の`if (url === "ブラックリストのurl"){}`で処理を変えたいのでこの処理より上でjsonファイルの中身を取得したい

#### 分からないこと

- manifestの`content_scripts`の`content.js`では非同期処理は出来ないのか
- `content.js`内で相対パスでblocked.jsonをしているが読み取られない

以下のコードで実行すると、そもそも`blocked.json`がgetできないとconsoleでエラーが吐かれます。
そして、 "getできません。" と表示されているurlが`GET https://demosite/blocked.json 404`のように拡張機能内のjsonファイルではなくサイトのjsonファイルを参照しようとしてエラーが吐かれているようです。

ご回答いただければ幸いです。

---

現在ディレクトリ構造は下記のようになっています。

```
 extension
 ├── js
 │   ├── blocked.json
 │   ├── content.js
 │   └── inject.js
 └── manifest.json
```

manifest

```
{
  "name": "Blocking phishing sites",
  "description": "Control method for web push notification by browser extension",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "web_accessible_resources": [
    "js/content.js",
    "js/blocked.json"
  ],
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
      "run_at": "document_start",
      "js": ["js/inject.js"]
    }
  ],
  "permissions": [
    "*://*/*",
    "tabs",
    "webRequest",
    "webRequestBlocking",
    "webNavigation"
  ]
}
```

blocked.json

```
{
  "keyword":[
    "test",
    "test_1",
    "test_2",
    "test_3"
  ],

  "url":[
    "https://example.com/",
    "https://example_1.com/",
    "https://example_2.com/",
    "https://example_3.com/"
  ]
}
```

inject.js

```
console.log("-- inject script --");
const script = document.createElement("script");
script.src = chrome.runtime.getURL("js/content.js");
(document.head || document.documentElement).insertAdjacentElement("afterbegin", script);


console.log("-- load json --");
const blockedPath = "js/blocked.json";
const s = document.createElement("script");
s.jsonUrl = chrome.runtime.getURL(blockedPath);

console.log("blockedPath: ", s.jsonUrl);

fetch(s.jsonUrl)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
      console.log(data);
      console.log(data.url[0]);
    });
```

content.js

```
・・・省略・・・

window.open = function (open) {
  return function (url, name, features) {
    console.log("url: ", url);

    //jsonの中身とurlを比較
    if (url === "ブラックリストのurl") {
      console.log("url blocked!");
      return null;
    } else {
      return open.call(window, url, name, features);
    }

  };
}(window.open);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

相対URLは表示しているページのURLからの相対になるので、この用途には使えません。

`blocked.json` を [`web_accessible_resources`](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/manifest/web_accessible_resources/) に指定して、[`chrome.runtime.getURL()`](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/runtime/#method-getURL)の結果を`fetch()`に渡します。

Comment: `content.js`の1~4行目を追記したのですが、console上で`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getURL')`とエラーが吐かれてしまいます、

認識としては、`content.js`内で`chrome.runtime.getURL()`を行いその結果を`content.js`内で`fetch()`に渡すということで間違いないでしょうか？

Comment: あ、構成を見誤ってました。content.js はコンテントスクリプトではないのですね。では content.js 内で chrome.runtime は利用できません。
inject.js 内で chrome.runtime.getURL() と fetch() を行い、その結果を何とかしてHTML中に挿入する必要があります。

Comment: 拡張機能内にhtmlを配置する必要があるということですね、なるほどです。
「htmlに挿入はするが表示はしない」ように実装できればjsonファイル内の値をcontent.js内で変数に入れて比較できそうですかね、、

Comment: JSONなので、`"const json = " + fetchで得たテキスト + ";"` のような文字列を `<script>` で囲って挿入すればいいです。

Comment: ありがとうございます！inject.jsの`console.log("-- load json --");`より下のコードを追加したことでconsole上でblocked.jsonの中身を表示できました。

これ以降が自分の中でうまく理解できていないのですが、これをcontent.jsで操作したい場合は、一旦inject.jsからhtmlに`<script>`挿入してcontent.jsで拾うのでしょうか？

Comment: はい。response.json() を response.text() に変えて、その結果で私の前のコメントの文字列を作って、それを s.textContent  に代入して、s を script と同じように insertAdjacentElement() すればよいです。content.js の中からは変数 json が見えるはずです。

Comment: int32_t さん ありがとうございます！おっしゃる通り、inject.jsでtextとして<script>でサイトに挿入してcontent.jsで挿入した<script>内のものを扱うことが出来ました。ありがとうございます！